# Cleaning up a function

Tags: javascript, function

So, guys, I have a strange question... 
I have this code:

```js
var valuesForLakewood = (function (m, k) { 
      return m[k] === undefined ? null : m[k]; 
    })(this.lakewood, customerType);
    var valuesForBridgewood = (function (m, k) { 
      return m[k] === undefined ? null : m[k]; 
    })(this.bridgewood, customerType);
    var valuesForRidgewood = (function (m, k) { 
      return m[k] === undefined ? null : m[k]; 
    })(this.ridgewood, customerType);
    lakewoodCost = weekdays * valuesForLakewood[0] 
      + weekends * valuesForLakewood[1];
    bridgewoodCost = weekdays * valuesForBridgewood[0] 
      + weekends * valuesForBridgewood[1];
    ridgewoodCost = weekdays * valuesForRidgewood[0] 
      + weekends * valuesForRidgewood[1];
    var hotel = 
      this.minCost(lakewoodCost, bridgewoodCost, ridgewoodCost);
```

I just need to clean it up a little bit. I repeat the same function over and over again and I would like your opinion on how I can clean this up a little bit, reducing the size of my code. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you might be looking for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if your code is working

Comment: Obvious first step would be to extract the repeated `function (m, k) { 
      return m[k] === undefined ? null : m[k]; 
    }` into a named declaration

Answer (score 0):

Use a single function to extract the values from the object, two arrays instead of six standalone variables, destructuring to make the total cost operation more understandable, and then spread the resulting array into `minCost`:

```
const getVal = obj => obj[customerType] === undefined ? null : obj[customerType];
const values = [this.lakewood, this.bridgewood, this.ridgewood].map(getVal);
const costs = values.map(([weekdayCost, weekendCost]) => weekdays * weekdayCost + weekends * weekendCost);
const hotel = this.minCost(...costs);
```

Comment: You rock! Thank you!

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)